# When uploading React app to server all routes except "/" return Internal Server Error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-500

This is the first time I'm uploading a React app to a server (a GoDaddy one if it's relevant), for doing so i run "npm run build" as it says in the package.json, and then uploaded the build files through FileZilla.
The landing page works alright until i want to redirect to another page like "/quiz" for example. Then i get the following message
"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
[...]
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

I've tried changing all the file permissions to 0755 in FileZilla and nothing happened.
I'm thinking that maybe when i tried deploying to github pages in the past i may have changed something important in package.json

I would like to know if it's a mistake i'm doing in react router (that I put in App.js), a package.json mistake or it's on the server side.

You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/DairaF/lenguaje-inclusivo)

Comment: Have you looked at the webserver error logs?

Comment: I have never done that, I'm sorry if it's basic. I just googled how but i'm not quite sure, is it something i can access without having access to the cpanel (my client hasn't given me the data to have access, only the ftp account and such)? does the Windows event viewer suffice?

Comment: Read through [serving apps with client side routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) and see if anything there helps you. The gist is that your server needs to be configured to redirect requests for your nested routes to your root index.html file so your app loads and handles the internal navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a '.htaccess' in your build folder.

Add these lines of codes inside the '.htaccess' folder

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Or maybe you should consider looking in your server files configuration. For Apache [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/q20206/howto/htaccess.html).

Comment: It did need an .htaccess, now it works fine. Thank you for your help!